# How Can I Change Background Color of Row based on cell value in Datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I have a datatable that has 8 columns that one column is hidden.I want to change background color of the row that the "Durum" column value is "Aktif" to be Green and column value "Pasif" to be Red.I have used "fnRowCallback" and "createdRow" functions but i cant manage to change the color.ı added my code below.Where am i doing wrong?Please help me..

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="RaporProject.AdminLogin" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>AdminLogin</title>
     <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="Content/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="Content/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="Content/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#UserList').DataTable({
                "aLengthMenu": [[4, 8, 12, -1], [4, 8, 12, "All"]],
                "iDisplayLength": 4,
                "bFilter": false,
                "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]],
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    if (aData[5] == "Aktif") {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Green');
                    }
                    else if (aData[5] == "Pasif") {
                        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                    }
                },
                select: {
                    style: 'single'
                },
                language: {
                    url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Turkish.json'
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#UserList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var tableData = $(this).children("td").map(function () {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();

           // alert("Your data is: " + $.trim(tableData[0]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[1]) + " , " + $.trim(tableData[2]));
            $('#Hidden1').val(tableData);
            });
        });


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">
           <asp:HiddenField ID="Hidden1" runat="server" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
           <h5>Merhaba  <asp:LinkButton ID="lblKullaniciAdi" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" OnClick="lblKullaniciAdi_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton> </h5>
           <h5><asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" CssClass="pull-right" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" Font-Underline="True">Log Out</asp:LinkButton> </h5>
        <h2>Kullanıcılar</h2>     
        </div>
     <div style="float:right">
      <asp:Button ID="btn_KullaniciEkle" class="btn btn-primary"   runat="server"  Text="Yeni Kullanıcı Ekle"  OnClick="btn_KullaniciEkle_Click"/>      
        </div>
<h1>Kullanıcı Listesi</h1>
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptUsers" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="UserList">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="hidden">ID</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Kullanıcı Adı</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Ad</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Soyad</th>
<th style="text-align:center">IsAdmin</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Durum</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Rapor Göster</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Sil</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="hidden">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSira" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td> 
                <td style="pointer-events:none;text-align:center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblKullaniciAdi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KullaniciAdi") %>' />
                </td>
                  <td style="pointer-events:none;text-align:center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad") %>' />
                </td>
                  <td style="pointer-events:none;text-align:center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSoyad" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Soyad") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td style="pointer-events:none;text-align:center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsAdmin") %>' />
                </td>
                 <td style="pointer-events:none;text-align:center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDurum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Durum") %>' />
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Show" class="btn btn-primary center-block" OnClick="btn_Show_Click"  runat="server" Text="Göster"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" class="btn btn-danger center-block" OnClick="btn_Delete_Click" runat="server"  Text="Sil" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody> </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use OnItemDataBound on repeater?

Comment: How Can i use it,can you give me an example? @ZP Baloch

Comment: i have added a function of jquery if that doesn't work I'll send you server side function.

Comment: @ZPBaloch  
I am sorry,that function doesnt work

Comment: answer updated and second approach added as other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this function

```
<style type="text/css">
    .clrGreen{
        background-color:green;
    }
    .clrRed{
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#UserList > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
            debugger;
            var durumValue = $(this).find(".lblDurum").html();
            switch (durumValue) {
                case "Aktif":
                    $(this).addClass("clrGreen");
                    break;
                case "Pasif":
                    $(this).addClass("clrRed");
                    break;
            };
            });
    })
</script>
```

her is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryc57r8c/)

Comment: try using class for label instead of id because id is unique.
Answer update

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution to your question no jquery/javascript required

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptUsers" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="UserList">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hidden">ID</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Kullanıcı Adı</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Ad</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Soyad</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">IsAdmin</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Durum</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Rapor Göster</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center">Sil</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr class="<%# Eval("Durum") %>">
                <td class="hidden">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSira" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="pointer-events: none; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblKullaniciAdi" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("KullaniciAdi") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="pointer-events: none; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAd" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Ad") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="pointer-events: none; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSoyad" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Soyad") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="pointer-events: none; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAdmin" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsAdmin") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="pointer-events: none; text-align: center">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDurum" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Durum") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Show" class="btn btn-primary center-block" OnClick="btn_Show_Click" runat="server" Text="Göster" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Delete" class="btn btn-danger center-block" OnClick="btn_Delete_Click" runat="server" Text="Sil" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody> </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

and add in style

```
.Aktif{ background-color: green;}
.Pasif{ background-color: red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could then try createdCell

```
"createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
  if ( cellData == "Aktif" ) {
    $(row).css('background-color', 'Green');
  }
  else if (cellData == "Pasif") {
    $(row).css('background-color', 'Red');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `fnRowCallback` function as below:

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data, index ) {
      $node = this.api().row(row).nodes().to$();

  if (data[5] == "Aktif") {
     $node.addClass('green')
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.green{
  background-color: green!important;
}
```

Comment: Try to add debug the code - add the console.log(data[5]) and check which value is getting?

Comment: the value is "Aktif"

Comment: ok, you got the value but the color is not changed... By looking in to inspect element check the CSS class "green" applied on the td or not? Maybe it will be overridden by some other class...